# Sentences ending with both a colon and a question mark

Tags: punctuation, questions, colons

How should sentences that end with both a colon and a question mark be formed? Two examples are below, both questions, but one in which the colon presents a piece of information and the other in which it begins a list.

> Is this the one you meant?: http://example.com/somebody/blog/article/foobarbaz.gif

> Do you have any of these symptoms?:
>
> - Headache
> - Nausea
> - Dizziness

Obviously a question-mark—colon combination is no good, and at best, looks odd. Putting the question mark after the item(s) is no good either. Do they have to be rewritten in a more pointed way such as below or is there another option?

> Is the one in the following picture the one you meant?
> http://example.com/somebody/blog/article/foobarbaz.gif

> Do you have any of the symptoms below?
>
> - Headache
> - Nausea
> - Dizziness

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec067.html) notes:

> Many writers assume—wrongly—that a colon is always needed before a
> series or a list. [Section 6.67]

So dispense with the colon entirely:

> Is this the one you meant?
>
> - http://blah.com/somebody/blog/article/foobarbaz.gif

Alternatively:

> Is this the one you meant:
> http://blah.com/somebody/blog/article/foobarbaz.gif ?

Or:

> Do you have any of the symptoms below?
>
> - Headache
> - Nausea
> - Dizziness

Comment: I like the note about colon usage in terms of lists, but I don’t think it applies to the first case (introduction of a specific piece of related information). I already make a habit of putting URLs on a separate, indented line.

Comment: I agree that it's clearer that way. I suggested the one-line alternative as perhaps the least bad way if space was tight.

Comment: Yes, if you have something like a URL that includes punctuation symbols, it's best not to surround it with any other punctuation marks.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could simply do this.

Did you mean http://blah.com/somebody/blog/article/foobarbaz.gif?

Comment: I thought of that but the question mark is displaced by a significant amount, especially with a longer URL. And it does not address a list. `Did you mean this http://foobar.baz/blah/someone/site/search?query=something&width=1024&height=768;q=5&otherstuff=somethingelse;flashvars=one%20other%25thing%226?`

Comment: It would go like this:  Did you mean a, b or c, substituting  in the URLs.  This would be grammatically correct.   So you could still structure the sentence the same way.

Comment: That’s fine with *really* short things, but it would be incredibly unwieldy and illegible with long things like URLs, but even with shorter things like words or phrases.

Comment: It's incredibly unwieldy and illegible just to include a long URL, as above.

Answer (score 1):

Not one of my many books addresses it, but I have seen examples on the Internet (by self-proclaimed experts) that seem to settle the matter.

In short, when two punctuation marks are both appropriate, use the one that makes the sentence more clear:

> She yelled, "Duck!" and we hit the ground.

The exclamation point replaced the comma, and the meaning is better served.  Here is another case:

> The report claimed that the employees "...engaged in industrial sabotage..." but I couldn't confirm it.

Again, the lost comma is not missed.

On the question of the colon and the question mark together, I have seen the same recommendation. Which of them is more essential to the meaning?  Use that one.

But I can't find definitive answers in any "official" books on the matter.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend using "Do you have any of the symptoms below?" It is awkward. There is nothing wrong with using a question mark followed by a colon. You might have just been looking at it for too long. Everything starts to look a little funny if you stare at it long enough.

Answer (score -1):

Writers are typically narcissistic and not amenable to constructive criticism, but speaking from the stance of an English major and experienced Editor, it is NOT okay to use both a question mark and semi-colon to end a passage.

Comment: That aligns with what [this website](http://www.loc.gov/nls/other/annotation/subtitles.html) says: _A question mark or exclamation point is sufficient for separation. Do not also use a colon._