# Using a colon following a question

Tags: colons, question-mark

Can you use a colon following a question mark? I am not sure about the colon and/or capitalization when adding the list of characteristics.

> Which of the following characteristics do you automatically associate with women?: Decisive, pushy, assertive, competitive, collaborative.

Comment: You would use a colon in this case to imply "choose from the following" but you have already said that at the beginning of your sentence. so perhaps the colon is not necessary?

Comment: Also: if this is from a questionnaire you are designing, you could arrange the list of characteristics on a separate (next) line, with no capitalisation, since the list would not be a sentence.

Comment: Personally I would use the colon but I would place the question mark at the end of the sentence, i.e. after *collaborative*.

Comment: Same question already answered: [Sentences ending with both a colon and a question mark](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51485/sentences-ending-with-both-a-colon-and-a-question-mark) Another useful reference: [Colon before or after question mark](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/colon-before-or-after-the-question-mark.1232145/)

Comment: One more example: [Grammarboook.com](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/colons/colons-continued/#comment-4818)