# Punctuation marks just before colon or semi-colon

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, colons, end-punctuation

Is it possible to use punctuation marks such as commas, periods, and question marks just before colons or semi-colons?

> The error appears when accessing some URLs, e.g**.:**
>
> - List items ...

> Can I set additional parameters for the following tasks**?:**
>
> - List items ...

I occasionally come up with such sentences due to perhaps my mother tongue (Japanese). However, I realised that such usages can't find anywhere so it might not be natural usage for native speakers. Any natural alternative ways to write it?

Comment: This is really 2 separate questions. [There is a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51485/sentences-ending-with-both-a-colon-and-a-question-mark) about "?:" (please don't do that.) There's a question on English Language Learners about [abbreviations like "Vehicle Chassis No.:"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71155/how-do-we-punctuate-an-abbreviation-followed-by-a-colon) which are fine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I couldn't find the previous answers.